# How to get data-timestamp using python/selenium

Tags: python, selenium

Below is the html of the table I want to extract the data-timestamp from.
[image]

The webpage is at https://nl.soccerway.com/national/argentina/primera-division/20182019/regular-season/r47779/matches/?ICID=PL_3N_02

So far I tried verious variants I found on here but nothing seemed to work. Can someone help me to extract the (for example) 1536962400. So in other words I want to extract every data-timestamp value of the table. Any suggestions are more than welcome! I have used selenium/python to extract table data from the website but data-timestamp always gives errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

data-timestamp is an attribute of tr element, you can try this:

```
element_list = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table[contains(@class,'matches')]/tbody/tr")
for items in element_list:
    print(items.get_attribute('data-timestamp'))
```

Comment: you sir are a genious! Works like a charm!